# ansible question to execute and display multiple commands

Tags: ansible

I have the simple ansible script below:

```
- hosts: myhost
  tasks:
    - name: few commands
      command: "{{ item }}"
      with_items:
        - ls -l
        - df -h
        - cat /tmp/1
```

there will be more commands and files, how I can display the execution of each command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could use `-vvv` to get the output of the commands while running the playbook:

```
changed: [localhost] => (item=echo helloworld) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
    "changed": true, 
    "cmd": [
        "echo", 
        "helloworld"
    ], 
    "delta": "0:00:00.002517", 
    "end": "2019-12-20 15:20:09.042020", 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "echo helloworld", 
            "_uses_shell": false, 
            "argv": null, 
            "chdir": null, 
            "creates": null, 
            "executable": null, 
            "removes": null, 
            "stdin": null, 
            "stdin_add_newline": true, 
            "strip_empty_ends": true, 
            "warn": true
        }
    }, 
    "item": "echo helloworld", 
    "rc": 0, 
    "start": "2019-12-20 15:20:09.039503", 
    "stderr": "", 
    "stderr_lines": [], 
    "stdout": "helloworld", 
    "stdout_lines": [
        "helloworld"
    ]
}
```